# How to remove duplicate fields and create a sub-list out of them in python?

Tags: python

```
[{u'cloud_account': UUID('a639efb6-d4e0-4929-b309-8171bf61b508'), u'_id': UUID('d0576830-df96-4411-ac33-4bac597f2010')}, 

{u'cloud_account': UUID('a639efb6-d4e0-4929-b309-8171bf61b508'), u'_id': UUID('a650e642-ee41-4ab7-8ad1-797c7bdcd2aa')}, 

{u'cloud_account': UUID('a639efb6-d4e0-4929-b309-8171bf61b508'), u'_id': UUID('c0a36d2e-f7dd-4d62-abe8-c26249e52520')}, 

{u'cloud_account': UUID('fd4bbf86-9803-4724-9576-d83355bdcff2'), u'_id': UUID('31140d2e-15a1-4203-bdbb-55c14cd6b83a')}])
```

The '_id' field refers to the ids of machine_groups, I would like to have a sub-list that regroups those ids for the first cloud account.

Comment: Can you post your expected output?

Comment: [{u'cloud_account': UUID('a639efb6-d4e0-4929-b309-8171bf61b508'), u'_id': UUID('d0576830-df96-4411-ac33-4bac597f2010'),  u'_id': UUID('a650e642-ee41-4ab7-8ad1-797c7bdcd2aa'), u'_id': UUID('c0a36d2e-f7dd-4d62-abe8-c26249e52520')}, 

    {u'cloud_account': UUID('fd4bbf86-9803-4724-9576-d83355bdcff2'), u'_id': UUID('31140d2e-15a1-4203-bdbb-55c14cd6b83a')}])

Answer (score 0):

## List of machine groups per cloud account

Something like this could help:

```
cloud_accounts = [
    {'cloud_account': 'a639efb6-d4e0-4929-b309-8171bf61b508', '_id': 'd0576830-df96-4411-ac33-4bac597f2010'},
    {'cloud_account': 'a639efb6-d4e0-4929-b309-8171bf61b508', '_id': 'a650e642-ee41-4ab7-8ad1-797c7bdcd2aa'},
    {'cloud_account': 'a639efb6-d4e0-4929-b309-8171bf61b508', '_id': 'c0a36d2e-f7dd-4d62-abe8-c26249e52520'},
    {'cloud_account': 'fd4bbf86-9803-4724-9576-d83355bdcff2', '_id': '31140d2e-15a1-4203-bdbb-55c14cd6b83a'}]

machine_groups_per_cloud_account = {d['cloud_account']: [] for d in cloud_accounts}
for d in cloud_accounts:
    machine_groups_per_cloud_account[d['cloud_account']].append(d['_id'])

import pprint
pprint.pprint(machine_groups_per_cloud_account)
```

Here is the output:

```
{'a639efb6-d4e0-4929-b309-8171bf61b508': ['d0576830-df96-4411-ac33-4bac597f2010', 'a650e642-ee41-4ab7-8ad1-797c7bdcd2aa', 'c0a36d2e-f7dd-4d62-abe8-c26249e52520'], 
 'fd4bbf86-9803-4724-9576-d83355bdcff2': ['31140d2e-15a1-4203-bdbb-55c14cd6b83a']}
```

In the result example you gave, you have multiple times the same keys in a `dict`, it is incorrect, so the idea here is to consider `cloud_account` as python dict keys and append `_id` in a associated list (python dict value).

## Number of machines per cloud account

```
machine_groups = [
    {'count': 1, '_id': '31140d2e-15a1-4203-bdbb-55c14cd6b83a'},
    {'count': 17, '_id': 'c0a36d2e-f7dd-4d62-abe8-c26249e52520'},
    {'count': 1, '_id': 'a650e642-ee41-4ab7-8ad1-797c7bdcd2aa'},
    {'count': 1, '_id': 'd0576830-df96-4411-ac33-4bac597f2010'}]
machine_groups_reorganized = {}
for m in machine_groups:
    machine_groups_reorganized[m['_id']] = m['count']

machine_count_per_cloud_account = {d['cloud_account']: 0 for d in cloud_accounts}
for d in cloud_accounts:
    machine_count_per_cloud_account[d['cloud_account']] += machine_groups_reorganized[d['_id']]

import pprint
pprint.pprint(machine_count_per_cloud_account)
```

Here is the output:

```
{'a639efb6-d4e0-4929-b309-8171bf61b508': 19,
 'fd4bbf86-9803-4724-9576-d83355bdcff2': 1}
```

Comment: Odly, it only returns an array of the cloud_accounts

Comment: I've got it working well using your `data` variable and my sample code as it is: `res = {'a639efb6-d4e0-4929-b309-8171bf61b508': ['d0576830-df96-4411-ac33-4bac597f2010', 'a650e642-ee41-4ab7-8ad1-797c7bdcd2aa', 'c0a36d2e-f7dd-4d62-abe8-c26249e52520'], 'fd4bbf86-9803-4724-9576-d83355bdcff2': ['31140d2e-15a1-4203-bdbb-55c14cd6b83a']}`

Comment: When you say `data` you mean the first array I posted ?

Comment: @BrokenStrings yes indeed

Comment: Can you please share the whole code and how you tested it ?

Comment: @BrokenStrings I edited my answer with the full sample code

Comment: Thanks, it worked finally. My aim now is to create a dict fetching this one with ```[{u'count': 1, u'_id': UUID('31140d2e-15a1-4203-bdbb-55c14cd6b83a')}, {u'count': 17, u'_id': UUID('c0a36d2e-f7dd-4d62-abe8-c26249e52520')}, {u'count': 1, u'_id': UUID('a650e642-ee41-4ab7-8ad1-797c7bdcd2aa')}, {u'count': 1, u'_id': UUID('d0576830-df96-4411-ac33-4bac597f2010')}]``` in order to get an array containing number of machines per cloud_account

Comment: the previous array is the number of machines per machine_group

Comment: then you can increase a counter instead of creating an array of machines ID per machine group:
`res = {d['cloud_account']: 0 for d in data}`
`for d in data: res[d['cloud_account']] += 1`

Comment: actually, there is no way to get the number of machines per cloud_account other then getting first the number of machines per machine_group an the mahcine_groups per cloud_account, that's because I'm using mongodb

Comment: so what you suggested gives the number of machine_groups not the number of machines per cloud_account

Comment: @BrokenStrings I think you definitely need to change the way you organize your data (look at `machine_groups_reorganized` variable) and take advantages of the python dictionaries (c.f. edited answer)

Comment: the problem is that those data sets are results of mongodb aggregation functions, they are in fact cursors, I don't know how to exploit them as dicts

Comment: sure no problem, so you just have to convert them to Python dictionaries as I demonstrated to you in my answer then :) does it work for you?

Comment: I did and I keep getting this error ```TypeError: 'CommandCursor' object has no attribute '__getitem__'```